# Glassfish not updating JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, glassfish

I have been using Glassfish 3.1 for a web project, even after updating a JavaScript file, and re-publishing the whole project onto the glassfish server, server seems to execute the older version of file. 
I have tried, restarting the server, but everything went in vain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I assume you are entirely sure that even if you packed an updated script still the old script version is rendered on the page. However I would advice to double check it.

You have some options here:

**First option**
If it is a developer machine and just one time problem with cache you can quickly fix it by deleting applications, generated and osgi-cache folders from your GLASSFISH_HOME. Before you should stop your AS though.

**Second option**
If you do not want your page to be cashed you can create a `javax.servlet.Filter` and add `Expires` header to a response in the `doFilter` method. If you use some date in the past the page will never be  cached.

```
  ((HttpServletResponse) resp).addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
```

Alternatively you can calculate a value and that would be your strategy for caching.

**Third Option**
You can add a parameter to your page URL. For example http(s)://{YOUR_URL}/${PATH_TO_PAGE}?version={APP_VERSION}

You do not have to read or process this parameter, so you do not care about either its name or value, but if in your application you will increase {APP_VERSION} each time you upgrade your app and navigate to the page adding this parameter, it will make the page URL unique for each application version and you can be sure cached version from previous version is not used. This way of course a bit awkward, nevertheless it is still an option. BTW this is a good way to check if you really ran into a cache related problem. Just add a random parameter to your page URL with a random value and you should see the latest script version.

**Forth Option**
You can somehow combine these option

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Glassfish problem. This is because your browser caches the js files.

You just have to clear your browser cache.